# How do Russian speakers see the preposition "у" in "отобрать у тебя что-то"?

Tags: предлоги

> отобрать **у** тебя что-то

The preposition *у* usually refers to something being in someone's possession, so this phrase should literally translate as:

> take away **your** (something/belongings/house/car)

But I wonder if native speakers perhaps see it as:

> take away (something/everything/a car) **from** you

... even though the preposition *у*, in and of itself, does not have the sense of "from/**от**"?

Comment: What is the difference between these 2 English phrases? Because there is almost no difference, for instance, between я отберу твой дом and я отберу у тебя дом, maybe the latter has slightly more emphasis on the fact that the house is really yours and it will be you who will suffer, i.e. on this fact of posession

Comment: ***take away from (what's) yours***, ***take away from your possession*** if that makes any sense, i believe this is indeed Ablative case

Comment: In `у тебя` there is no stress that the "thing" belongs to this person. So, it "from someone".

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка - There's **no** Ablative case in the systems of English or Russian, you **can't** use that term while talking about them. Both **from you** and **у тебя** answer the question _where?_

Comment: @Yellow Sky well formally even Locative isn't recognized in the 'official' system of Russian cases, which nevertheless doesn't preclude its actual existence, but learning language, especially a foreign one, isn't about formalism, it's about understanding and concepts... *from you* answers the question *from whom?*, *у тебя* can answer two questions *at whom?* (as you seem to acknowledge in your reply) and *from whom?*

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка - Come on, Locative is a subset of Prepositional with it's distinct ending, _о лесе - в лесу_. But you can't give any examples of Ablative endings distinct from the endings of other cases. However much you can speak about Ablative _theoretically_, nevertheless you cannot present any material evidence of its existence. What are the endings of Russian Ablative? Or you mean there are Russian cases formed analytically? Either way, your answer will be easy to criticize.

Comment: @Yellow Sky my answer is just a means to help a learner to get the idea, also cases govern semantic relationships between parts of speech and some of them don't have distinct morphological expression being homonymous with other cases yet still retaining their semantic features, i think cases can be recognized where prepositions are followed by unexpected inflexion, like in *годиться в отцы*, *играть в казаки-разбойники*, *идти в космонавты*, admittedly this is not the case with *забрать у меня*

Answer (score 4):

The things can be looked at differently, and I'll try to explain it.
I'll begin with another verb, **брать у** ('take from'). The idea of how the preposition `y` denotes possession is following: `y` actually means "near, at", so

> **у стены** means '*at the wall, near the wall*'.

That's why

> **у Петра** actually means '*at Peter's*'

and

> **У Петра есть машина** is '*At Peters there's a-car*'.
>
> **Я брал книги у Петра** is something like '*I took books at Peter's.*'

And if we speak about **отобрать у**, it's almost the same, with an interesting exception of the prefix **ото-** which is a positional variant of the prefix **от-** derived from the preposition **от**, 'from'.
What I mean is, this prefix **ото-** corresponds to the English 'away' in **take away from**. Since 'away' has almost the same meaning as 'from', it's the English manner of constructing the phrase **take away from** which looks rather strange, it's almost the same as saying ***take from from**, while the Russian **отобрать у** is pretty logical, it's like ***from-take at**.

Answer (score 1):

**у** does have the sense of “from”:

> **4.** Указывает на источник получения, приобретения чего-л. *Взял книгу у товарища. Отобрали мячик у ребёнка. У соседей раздобыли немного муки. У кого ты это взяла? Сейчас же отдай назад! У кого нам помощи просить? Учись у товарищей. У кого бы взять денег в долг?*

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%83&all=x)